# Binary relational structures in which all binary relations are equivalence relations

Tags: reference-request, model-theory

I’m interested in (finite) binary relational structures (i.e. relational structures with only unary and binary relations) in which all binary relations are equivalence relations.

Is there a name for such relational structures? Do they have some characterisations?

Any reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: What kind of characterizations are you interested in? I doubt there's any clearer description than "binary relational structure in which all binary relations are equivalence relations".

Comment: @AlexKruckman to be honest, I don't know what kind of characterization exactly I'm looking for. Perhaps, I would like to know if this class of relational structures was studied for some reason and what is known about it.

Comment: Well, one fact is that the theory of such a structure is always stable.